# SQL Update values from multiple tables

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following sql. I just want to update 2 fields from the table **t1** and 1 field from **t2**. I tried to join the **t2** but it doesnt work. Is it possible to update two tables?

And i want to update the t2.field with a const variable.

so that i get something like this

```
UPDATE test1_00 t1
                      SET (t1.field, 
                           t1.field,
                           t2.field = 5)

UPDATE test1_00 t1
                      SET (t1.field, 
                           t1.field,
                           t2.field) =
                        (SELECT test,
                                test,
                                test                                                    
                         FROM table(test_function(
                         02172,
                         'TEST',
                         date('2021-07-26'),
                         'TEST',
                         5455612)
                         ) 
                         join  test1 t1 on t1.id    = t2.id 
                         where t2.test              = test
                         and   t2.test              = test
                         );
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No.

An update can only update one table at a time.